# Order of polynomial, unique number of equations needed

Tags: linear-algebra

I am doing Linear Algebra and am working on a homework assignment and am quite confused.
The question is:

> Recall that R(x) is a rational function <-> R(x) = P(x)/Q(x) such that
>   P(x) & Q(x) are each polynomials.  If the order of P(x) = O[P(x)] = p
>   and O[Q(x)] = q, then, using p and q in your answer, what is the
>   minimum number of unique equations required to solve for R(x)?

I asked the teacher for clarification as I am quite confused and he replied:

> What does order refer to? What does it mean? I need to consider that
>   with regards to polynomials and how many unique equations you need to
>   solve for those polynomials… This is related to their order.

I understand that order is the highest power that a polynomial is raised to.
However I am completely lost with regards to the number of unique equations needed. Can anyone give me a push in the right direction?

EDIT: I understand that a polynomial of order 2 can be rewritten as the factor of its zeroes with 2 factors, order 3 can be rewritten as the factor of its zeroes with 3 factors, and so on.
However I am still a bit confused.
Would the expression in terms of p and q defined above be (n*p)/(m*q) where n is the order of the equation in the numerator and m is order of the equation in the denominator?

Comment: How many roots or zeroes does a polynomial of order p have? Then how can you rewrite the polynomial as factor of its zeroes?...hope this helps...

Comment: I have to admit that I don’t even understand the question... what means * ...equations to solve for $R(x)$*?

Comment: Forget about rationals functions for the moment and try to solve the same question for polynomials (or rational functions with constant denominator.)  How many equations do you need to determine a line? a parabola? a polynomial of degree $n$?  How does your answer change if you have a rational function?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Equations like $R(x_1)=y_1, R(x_2)=y_2,$ etc.

Comment: @Pi_die_die I have edited the question to update my understanding.

Comment: @saulspatz If I understand correctly we need one equation to define a line, and n equations to define a polynomial of degree n.
I have edited the question to reflect this, but am not 100% sure I am correct.

Comment: @RossSatchell Not quite.  A line has equation $y=ax+b,$ so you'll need two equations to solve for $a$ and $b$.  "Two points determine a line."

Comment: @saulspatz I had been thinking that it would be p-q, but then if the numbers was order 1 and denominator was order 2, I would get -1.

Comment: If a straight line requires 2 equations, then a order 2 equation should require 3 equations then?